# LocalNotification - How to use it?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, push-notification

I need to have push notifications on a Ionic (with Angular) app, I try to install LocalNotification but I can't achieve this, and there is no "tutorial" on how to install it.

Here is the git of LocalNotifications : https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-local-notifications

I install it with npm and then I try to use it like that :

```
export class PushService {

  constructor(private localNotifications: LocalNotifications) {}

  public testNotif() {
    // Schedule delayed notification
    this.localNotifications.schedule({
      text: 'Delayed ILocalNotification',
      led: 'FF0000',
      sound: null
    });
  }
}
```

But I always have this error : `NullInjectorError: No provider for LocalNotifications!`

The problem is that when I add LocalNotifications as a provider in my app.module then I have a new error :

```
Type 'LocalNotificationsOriginal' is not assignable to type 'Provider'.
```

What is wrong ? How to use it ?

Comment: i have the same issue, did you manage to solve the issue in the end?

Answer (score 4):

Just in case anyone encounters the same problem. From the documentation

> To use a plugin, import and add the plugin provider to your @NgModule,
>   and then inject it where you wish to use it. Make sure to import the
>   injectable class from the /ngx directory as shown in the following
>   examples:

```
// app.module.ts
import { Camera } from '@ionic-native/camera/ngx';

...

@NgModule({
  ...

  providers: [
    ...
    Camera
    ...
  ]
  ...
})
export class AppModule { }
```

The key takeaway here, it to add to providers in **app.module.ts** and not other modules where you might want to use it. In components just inject as per usual into the constructor() {}

Have tried this with localNotifications and it works.

Comment: I think the key takeaway here is to make sure you're importing from the `/ngx` directory. Using the WebStorm IDE it omits that directory and imports from `@ionic-native/local-notifications` which is not a provider.